# Can a bridge pin on a guitar effect the tuning up the neck

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

I had to replace a new bridge pin for my acoustic guitar, and the one I purchased is not quite the same as the other pins. Now that particular string is way out of tune up the neck (i.e. the harmonic at the 12th fret is way sharper than the actual 12th fret). All the rest of the strings are fine.

Could this be the bridge pin's fault and if so, how exactly? (I'm trying to imagine the physics of it).

Comment: Trying to think horses not zebras, I'm wondering how good a guitar it is, whether the bridge came out when you did the string change where you lost the bridge pin,  whether the strings were known to be well-intonated before the strings change, if a big change in string gauge occurred when you changed strings, etc. Acoustic guitars are not particularly adjustable, and while I could imagine pins having an effect on sustain, I can't see how it broke intonation.

Comment: A pic would help. Same gauge string relaced? Saddle moved?

Comment: I'd be swapping the pin for another, and seeing what effect that had on another string. But doubtful the pin has changed the intonation. Which string anyway?

Comment: My first pass guess is that the saddle came out and got put back backwards, but it could be so many other things

Answer (score 1):

Unless you somehow installed the pin in a way that drastically changed the actual position of the node at the bridge (first contact point with the string), the pin cannot have caused the location of the harmonic to move.  The harmonic is strictly found at 1/2 the length beteween neck and bridge nodes.